# How to format (customize) data tables in react

Tags: reactjs, datatable, datatables

I am new to react and datatables and currently working on my final year project
I have retrieved the data and managed to populate data into datatable but don't know how to format it.

How to format datatable like this:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJGy2.png)

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/ry6910y4jn?fontsize=14

Any suggestion hint would be helpful, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving this a shot by running the snippet below. The trick is to use `rowspan`.

That said, using React to render your multi-row, a naive approach might look something like:

```
const renderMultiRow = (code, date, rice, wheat, jaggery) => {
  return (
   <React.Fragment>
     <tr>
       <td rowspan="2">{code}</td>
       <td rowspan="2">{date}</td>
       <td>Stock</td>
       <td>{rice.stock}</td>
       <td>{wheat.stock}</td>
       <td>{jaggery.stock}</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Daily Use</td>
       <td>{rice.use}</td>
       <td>{wheat.stock}</td>
       <td>{jaggery.stock}</td>
     </tr>
   <React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Code</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Rice</th>
    <th>Wheat</th>
    <th>Jaggery</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1234</td>
      <td rowspan="2">2019-05-11</td>
      <td>Stock</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Daily Use</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">5678</td>
      <td rowspan="2">2019-05-12</td>
      <td>Stock</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Daily Use</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```